# Confusing moment from Theorem 10.43 from Rudin PMA

Tags: real-analysis, vector-analysis

[image]

Point $(b')$ little bit confuses me. Let $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}=0$ then $d\omega_{\mathbf{F}}=0$. We see that $\mathbf{F}\in C'$. Since $\omega_{\mathbf{F}}$ is closed in $E$ then by theorem 10.40 it is exact, i.e. exists $1$-form $\lambda$ such that $d\lambda=\omega_{\mathbf{F}}$. Also $\lambda$ assosiates to some vector field $\mathbf{G}$ in $E$, i.e. $d\lambda_{\mathbf{G}}=\omega_{\mathbf{F}}$. Hence $\mathbf{F}=\nabla\times \mathbf{G}$.

**Remark:** From $d\lambda_{\mathbf{G}}=\omega_{\mathbf{F}}$ we get: $$F_1=D_2G_3-D_3G_2\in C',$$ $$F_2=D_3G_1-D_1G_3\in C',$$ $$F_3=D_1G_2-D_2G_1\in C',$$
How he conclude that $G\in C''$? Because from above equalities does not follow that $G\in C''$.

Comment: $F = \nabla \times G$ alone doesn't imply that $G$ is of class $\mathscr{C}''$. You can find a vector field $H$ such that $H \notin \mathscr{C}''$, but $\nabla \times H = 0$ (it's not difficult to find such $H$). The assertion is that among all the $\mathscr{C}'$ vector fields with $\nabla \times G = F$, there is (at least) one that is of class $\mathscr{C}''$. That's probably true, but before I think about that, I need to have lunch.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Bon Appetit! :) It would be very interesting to read your idea!

Comment: @DanielFischer, Do you have any ideas about this?

Comment: If there is an obvious way to prove it, it's not in the direction I've looked so far. Needs more pen-and-paper time.

Comment: Because it's very weird he states that $u\in C''$ but no proof and hint :(

Comment: If you can prove it i would be very grateful for you valuable help! I spend some time on this but no results