# Rudin's PMA: theorem 10.43

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, vector-fields

---

This is the definition which we need for the proof of the theorem :
[image]

This is the definition of the $\mathscr C''$ - equivalent :

[image]

There is the theorem:

Suppose E is an open set in $R^3$, $u$ $\in$ $\mathscr C''(E)$, and $G$ is a vector field in $E$, of class $C''$ .

$(a)$ if $F$ $=$ $\nabla$$u$, then $\nabla$ $\times$ $F$ $=$ $0$ .

$(b)$ if $F$ $=$ $\nabla$ $\times$ $G$, then $\nabla$ $\cdot$ $F$ $=$ $0$.

Furthermore, if $E$ is $\mathscr C''$-equivalent to a convex set, then $(a)$ and $(b)$ have converses, in which we assume that $F$ is a vector field in $E$, of class $\mathscr C'$:

$(a')$ if $\nabla$ $\times$ $F$ $=$ $0$, then $F$ = $\nabla$$u$ for some $u$ $\in$ $\mathscr C''(E)$.

$(b')$ if $\nabla$ $\cdot$ $F$ $=$ $0$, then $F$ $=$ $\nabla$ $\times$ $G$ for some vector field $G$ in $E$, of class $\mathscr C''$

There is the proof  :

If we compare the definitions of $\nabla$$u$, $\nabla$ $\times$ $F$, and $\nabla$ $\cdot$ $F$ with the differential forms $\lambda_F$ and $\omega_F$ given by ($124$) and ($125$), we obtain the following four statements:

$F$ $=$ $\nabla$$u$   if and only if $\lambda_F$ $=$ $du$.                    ($\star$).

$\nabla$ $\times$ $F$ $=$ $0$ if and only if $d\lambda_F$ $=$ $0$.             ($\ast$)

$F$ $=$ $\nabla$ $\times$ $G$   if and only if $\omega_F$ $=$ $d\lambda_G$.  ($\oplus$)

$\nabla$ $\cdot$ $F$ $=$ $0$   if and  only if $d\omega_F$ $=$ $0$.            ($\circ$)

I could n't understand these four statements ($\star$),($\ast$),($\oplus$),($\circ$).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is $\mathscr C'$ defined?

Comment: @JMP Continuously differentiable functions class.

Comment: And how about $d$ and $D_i$? I assume $u=u(x,y,z)$.

Comment: @JMP yes you are right

Comment: From a function u, we have 2 procedure : one to form a vector field $\nabla u$ and another to form a 1-form with the exterior derivative.
The first statement is the same as saying that $\lambda$ allow to make a bijective link between the 2 procedure.
The other statement are basically the same, introducing the natural link between the exterior derivative and the different physical derivative introduced along history (gradiant, curl and divergence).
Don't know if this help ?

Comment: Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1787264/confusing-moment-from-theorem-10-43-from-rudin-pma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, $F=\nabla u$ iff $F_i=D_iu, i=1,2,3$ where $D_iu$ is the partial derivative of $u$ w.r.t. the $i$-th variable. Since $du=(D_1u)\,dx+(D_2u)\,dy+(D_3u)\,dz$, we have $\lambda_F=du$ is equivalent to $F_i=D_iu$ for all $i$ and hence equivalent to $F=\nabla u$.

For the second one, we have

\begin{align*}d\lambda_F=&dF_1\wedge dx+dF_2\wedge dy+dF_3\wedge dz\\
=&(D_1F_1\,dx+D_2F_1\,dy+D_3F_1\,dz)\wedge dx+(D_1F_2\,dx+D_2F_2\,dy+D_3F_2\,dz)\wedge dy\\&+(D_1F_3\,dx+D_2F_3\,dy+D_3F_3\,dz)\wedge dz
\end{align*}

where $dx\wedge dx=0$ and $dx\wedge dy=-dy\wedge dx$. Hence the above is equal to (after reorganizing terms)
$$d\lambda_F=(D_1F_2-D_2F_1)dx\wedge dy+(D_1F_3-D_3F_1)dx\wedge dz+(D_2F_3-D_3F_2)dy\wedge dz$$
Comparing this with $\nabla\times F$, we get the second statement.

For the third one, it is very similar to the second one.

For the last one,
\begin{align*}
d\omega_F&=dF_1\wedge dy\wedge dz+dF_2\wedge dz\wedge dx+dF_3\wedge dx\wedge dy\\
&=D_1F_1dx\wedge dy\wedge dz+D_2F_2dy\wedge dz\wedge dx+D_3F_3dz\wedge dx\wedge dy\\
&=(D_1F_1+D_2F_2+D_3F_3)dx\wedge dy\wedge dz
\end{align*}
Hence $d\omega_F=0$ iff $\nabla\cdot F=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The statements themselves are reasonable. Rudin proceeds:

$F=\nabla u \implies \lambda_F=du \implies d\lambda_F= 0 \implies \nabla \times F=0$.

$\nabla \times F=0 \implies d\lambda_F= 0 \implies \lambda_F=du \implies F=\nabla u $.

to prove statements (a) and (a').

$F=\nabla\times G \implies\omega_F=d\lambda_G\implies d\omega_F=0\implies \nabla\cdot F=0$

$\nabla\cdot F=0\implies d\omega_F=0 \implies \omega_F=d\lambda_G\implies F=\nabla\times G$

to prove statements (b) and (b').

All of the central 'implies' are justified using previous theorems in the book.